# Catching only certain (query)exception codes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, exception

I only want to handle certain query exception codes. The rest I want to let go; so that I get the regular debug or *Oops, something went wrong* screen, depending on my environment.

I currently have the following code in my `routes.php` file, it seems to work. But is it the correct way of doing it?

```
// Query Exceptions
App::error(function(QueryException $exception)
{
    $allowedCodes = array(
        '23000',            // Integrity constraint violation
    );

    if (in_array($exception->getCode(), $allowedCodes))
    {
        return Response::view('errors.show', array('code' => 'query_error_' . $exception->getCode()));
    }
    else
    {
        App::error(function(QueryException $exception){});
    }
});
```

**Update**, here was the solution I ended up based on Jarek Tkaczyk's answer:

```
App::error(function(QueryException $exception)
{
    $allowedCodes = array(
        '23000',            // Integrity constraint violation
    );

    if (in_array($exception->getCode(), $allowedCodes) && !App::environment('local'))
    {
        Log::warning('QueryException', array('context' => $exception->getMessage()));
        return Response::view('errors.show', array('code' => 'query_error_' . $exception->getCode()));
    }
});
```

Comment: Your `else` does nothing.

Comment: But it does seem to work as I intend, exception codes other than 23000 gives an debug exception message. Is that because I am not returning anything?

Comment: Yes, it works as expected. Howeveer `else` does this: Register empty error handler, while you are already in the error handler. This piece doesn't `re-throw` the error, as you asked in the q title, that's all.

Comment: I see, so what I am really doing is letting the exception slide through if not the "allowed" exception code?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Post this as an answer and I'll accept it, and change the question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is the way to go with one exception: `else` code block does basically nothing - it registers another handler for the exception that is being handled right now.

Here's something to make it more clear:

```
App::error(function(QueryException $exception)
{
    $allowedCodes = array(
        '23000',            // Integrity constraint violation
    );

    if (in_array($exception->getCode(), $allowedCodes))
    {
        return Response::view('errors.show', array('code' => 'query_error_' . $exception->getCode()));
    }

    // no need for else, it will handle exception like usually - depending on the debug config
});
```

or you could rethrow the exception and do pretty much the same:

```
App::error(function(QueryException $exception)
{
    $allowedCodes = array(
        '23000',            // Integrity constraint violation
    );

    if (in_array($exception->getCode(), $allowedCodes))
    {
        return Response::view('errors.show', array('code' => 'query_error_' . $exception->getCode()));
    }
    else
    {
        throw $exception; // this will show plain exception

        // or display whoops pretty handler:
        App::getFacadeApplication()->{'exception.debug'}->display($exception);

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me, and also showing me how to properly throw exceptions :)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it's the right way to do it.**

For the local environment you'd of course use environments [as described in Laravel's documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration).